# Get week no list only between two dates in different years

Tags: excel-formula

I want to generate list of week numbers list between two dates of different years. I followed below formula as per the image I have attached. I want get blank after Excel the end date. According to my formula it continues. Please advise.

```
=ISOWEEKNUM($A$1+7*(ROWS($B$3:B3)-1))
```

[image: Link for Image]

Comment: Looks like you wanted to include some image, but it not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **B3** enter:

```
=IF(A$1+7*(ROWS($1:1)-1)>B$1,"",ISOWEEKNUM(A$1+7*(ROWS($1:1)-1)))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the result should look like this...

[image]

...then you can use this formula:

```
=IF($A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1,3) +((ROW()-3)*7) <= $B$1-WEEKDAY($B$1,3), ISOWEEKNUM($A$1-WEEKDAY($A$1,3)+((ROW()-3)*7)), "")
```

Points to note:

1) It standardizes the dates on a first day of the week (Monday in this case).

2) It relies on `ROW()` - so the formula cells have to start in cell B3. This is what gives us the correct multiplier in increments of 7.

3) There may be a better (simpler) way.